# Easier way to return `impl Iterator<Item = T>` with `DoubleEndedIterator`, `ExactSizeIterator` and `FusedIterator` features

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits

In Rust you can use [`impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html) in a return signature to simplify the return type. In addition, it allows you to statically represent the "unnamed concrete type" of closures.

It is pretty common to just see `impl Iterator<Item = T>` in the signature, which is much easier to write than the exact return type. In addition, I believe this also makes your API stable against any change to the type of the returned iterator. For instance, you could swap out a `Vec` (`std::slice::Iter`) for a `VecDeque` (`std::collections::vec_deque::Iter`).

However I just discovered that this has a significant drawback. In the case that you need access to methods provided by `DoubleEndedIterator`, `ExactSizeIterator` and `FusedIterator` you have now accidently reduced the features of your returned iterator.

Consider [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5d82499af6aa8b620c8cc25ebc90257) on the Rust playground...

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct NewVec<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> NewVec<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> + DoubleEndedIterator {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let palindrome = NewVec(Vec::from(['R', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'R', '!']));
    println!("{:?}", palindrome);

    println!(
        "{}",
        palindrome
            .iter()
            .map(|character| format!("{}", character))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("")
    );

    println!(
        "{}",
        palindrome
            .iter()
            .rev()
            .map(|character| format!("{}", character))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("")
    );
}
```

The `iter` method on `NewStruct` cannot just return `impl Iterator<Item = &T>`, instead must return `impl Iterator<Item = &T> + DoubleEndedIterator` in order for `rev` to work.

This isn't the end of the world, but now signatures are `impl Iterator<Item = &T> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator + FusedIterator` in order to avoid a reduction in the features of the returned iterator.

*Is there a better way to achieve this? Do I really have to add `impl Iterator<Item = &T> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator + FusedIterator` on every function return type that returns an iterator if I do not want to restrict the underlying iterator?*

*Does this also imply that there may also be a performance impact in cases whereby the returned iterator does not specify that it also implements `ExactSizeIterator` and `FusedIterator`, even though underlying iterator actually does implement these traits?*

There is no way to make trait aliases at the moment. Type aliases do not work for traits and a trait alias can be emulated with [trait inheritance](https://tourofrust.com/80_en.html), however this introduces a new type which now needs to be exported.

Comment: Due to the way `FusedIterator` is implemented and documented (see the [note in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FusedIterator.html)), you can probably leave it off without any impact. The other traits would need to be kept in order to use their functionality.

Comment: You can also leave off `Iterator` since it's a supertrait, although you still need to put `Item = T` on one of the subtraits. Removing `ExactSizeIterator` is also not a big issue since `size_hint` will tell you if it's exact size in more cases anyway.

Comment: @kmdreko: Oh yeah, I'm aware `FusedIterator` doesn't provide any features, but as I mentioned above, could it have a performance impact if omitted?

Comment: @drewtato: I tried to remove the `Iterator`, but I couldn't find a way to get it to compile with just `DoubleEndedIterator`. For example, just `DoubleEndedIterator<Item = &T>` in my example only works with the `dyn` keyword.

Comment: Omitting `FusedIterator` will not have any perf impact because `fuse()` is using specialization so it will "see through" `impl Trait`.

Comment: @drewtato Apologies. `DoubleEndedIterator<Item =&T>` does work, I tested in a rush and had forgotten the `impl` keyword, hence the message about `dyn`.

Comment: Optimizations are performed on the actual generated code, so they are only affected by the actual return type and not by any bounds you give on the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit `FusedIterator`, since, [as noted in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FusedIterator.html), it should not be used in bounds but rather used as specialization in [`fuse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse), and specializations can "see through" `impl Trait`.

You can also omit `Iterator`, since it is a supertrait of both `DoubleEndedIterator` and `ExactSizeIterator`.

Which leaves us with these shorter bounds:

```rust
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl DoubleEndedIterator<Item = &T> + ExactSizeIterator {
    self.0.iter()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So a good practice would be to use `impl DoubleEndedIterator<Item = &T> + ExactSizeIterator` instead of `impl Iterator`, provided that your underlying iterator implements these traits and you do not want to restrict these features in your API? For example, just with a quick search I found `get_args` in [`clap`](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/ae16079120722d1e4820711a8f99a247d804b5ee/clap_builder/src/builder/arg_group.rs#L211), which while insignificant should probably have been less restrictive in their return signature?

Comment: Changing the return type from `impl Iterator<Item = T>` to `impl DoubleEndedIterator<Item = T> + ExactSizeIterator` would not be a breaking change to an API, right? However, it would be tedious if you needed the extra features provided by the additional traits, and then had to wait for the crate author to update their crate for it to work.

Comment: @scottwillmoore Yes, it won't be a breaking change. However, sometimes you _want_ to be more restrictive, to allow you more freedom when changing the function body.

Comment: @scottwillmoore Or just because, e.g. `DoubleEndedIterator` makes no sense, because there is no meaning to iterating backwards sometimes.